# How to round percentages with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got to print percentages, but the trick is that i have to round the values to 4 decimals.
It is in a DataFrame where each column represent the percentages for one allocation.

Sometimes, the sum of the percentages does not give 1, but 0.9999 or 1.0001 (which makes sense). But how do you make sure it does ?
You have to arbitrary pick a row and put the delta in it.
I've come up with this solution, but i've got to iterate through each column and do the modification on the Series.

**Code**

```
df = abs(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=range(0,4)))
# Making sure the sum of allocation is 1.
df = df / df.sum()
# Rounding the allocation
df = df.round(4)
print("-- before --")
print(df)
print(df.sum())

# It can happen that after rounding your number, the sum is not equal to 1. (imagine rounding 1/3 three times...)
# So check for the sum of each col and then put the delta in in the fund with the lowest value.
for p in df:
    if df[p].sum() != 1:
        # get the id of the fund with the lowest percentage (but not 0)
        low_id = (df[p][df[p] != 0].idxmin())
        df[p][low_id] += (1 - df[p].sum())
print("-- after --")
print(df)
print(df.sum())
```

**Output**

```
-- before --
        0       1       2       3
0  0.0116  0.1256  0.4980  0.3738
1  0.2562  0.5458  0.3086  0.1221
2  0.4853  0.0009  0.0588  0.0078
3  0.2470  0.3277  0.1346  0.4962
0    1.0001
1    1.0000
2    1.0000
3    0.9999
dtype: float64
-- after --
        0       1       2       3
0  0.0115  0.1256  0.4980  0.3738
1  0.2562  0.5458  0.3086  0.1221
2  0.4853  0.0009  0.0588  0.0079
3  0.2470  0.3277  0.1346  0.4962
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Is there any faster solution ?

Thanks a lot,

Regards,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to avoid loops.

```
df = abs(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4) ))

df = df / df.sum()
df = df.round(4)

columns = ['Sum','Min', 'submin']
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
dftemp['Sum']= df.sum(axis=0)     # sum columns
dftemp['Min']= df[df!=0].min(axis=0)   # non zero minimum of column
dftemp['submin']= dftemp['Min']+(1-dftemp['Sum'])  # (1 -sum of columns) + minimum value
dftemp['FinalValue']= np.where (dftemp['Sum']!=1,dftemp.submin,dftemp.Min)  # decide weather to use existing miinimum value or delta

print('\n\nBefore \n\n ',df,'\n\n ', df.sum())

df=df.mask(df.eq(df.min(0),1),df.eq(df.min(0),1).mul(dftemp['FinalValue'].tolist())) # Replace the minmum value with delta values

print('After \n\n ',df,'\n\n ', df.sum())
```

Output

Output

```
Before 

          0       1       2       3
0  0.1686  0.0029  0.1055  0.1739
1  0.5721  0.5576  0.2904  0.2205
2  0.0715  0.2749  0.4404  0.5014
3  0.1878  0.1647  0.1637  0.1042 

  0    1.0000
1    1.0001
2    1.0000
3    1.0000
dtype: float64
After 

          0       1       2       3
0  0.1686  0.0028  0.1055  0.1739
1  0.5721  0.5576  0.2904  0.2205
2  0.0715  0.2749  0.4404  0.5014
3  0.1878  0.1647  0.1637  0.1042 

  0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```